# Need some clarification on tmux

Tags: vim, configuration, tmux

I just installed tmux today, and I'm having some difficulty using it.
At the very bottom of the terminal window (I'm using iTerm2), it says the following: `[13] 0:zsh*`

What does the 13 mean? I know that there are 13 things saved. I don't know if they are windows, panes, or sessions. I have no idea; I want to clear them all, i.e., I want it to say `[0] 0:zsh*`

Also, vim looks really bad in tmux. I have seen that you need to run the command: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` but it does not work. And vim-airline looks really bad too. Without tmux running, however, vim looks just fine. If anyone can answer this for me, that would be amazing :)

UPDATE:

I tried using `tmux -2` command, but that also did not work. vim still looks bad, and upon typing `echo $TERM`, I get `screen` instead of `screen-256-color`

Comment: `tmux ls` lists the tmux sessions you have. [13] is your session name. If you don't specify it just increments. It doesn't necessarily mean you have 13 sessions active. As for vim looking bad... try `tmux -2`. The -2 forces tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colors.

Comment: thank you, I'm now able to handle sessions. However, upon entering `tmux -2`, vim still looks bad.

Comment: Is the issue colour related? You mentioned you're using airline? Maybe tmux isn't picking up utf8 support? Try `tmux -2 -u`. -u explicitly tells tmux utf8 is supported

Comment: that command: `tmux -2 -u` also did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I had this problem, it was because my vim colorscheme was using truecolor (24 bit) and tmux only supports 8bit (256 colors).

Here are the methods to check color support:

First, make sure you have 256 color support in your default terminal and tmux with this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (C) 2006 by Johannes Zellner, <johannes@zellner.org>
# modified by mac@calmar.ws to fit my output needs
# modified by crncosta@carloscosta.org to fit my output needs

import sys
import os

def echo(msg):
    os.system('echo -n "' + str(msg) + '"')

def out(n):
    os.system("tput setab " + str(n) + "; echo -n " + ("\"% 4d\"" % n))
    os.system("tput setab 0")

# normal colors 1 - 16
os.system("tput setaf 16")
for n in range(8):
    out(n)
echo("\n")
for n in range(8, 16):
    out(n)

echo("\n")
echo("\n")

y=16
while y < 231:
    for z in range(0,6):
        out(y)
        y += 1

    echo("\n")


echo("\n")

for n in range(232, 256):
    out(n)
    if n == 237 or n == 243 or n == 249:
        echo("\n")

echo("\n")
os.system("tput setaf 7")
os.system("tput setab 0")
```

The expected output is to have each line be a different color, with a max of 1 white line. If there are more lines with white text on black background, you do not have 256 colors enabled.

Next, check that you have truecolor support in your terminal/tmux with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Based on: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

awk -v term_cols="${width:-$(tput cols || echo 80)}" 'BEGIN{
    s="/\\";
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<term_cols; colnum++) {
        r = 255-(colnum*255/term_cols);
        g = (colnum*510/term_cols);
        b = (colnum*255/term_cols);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum%2+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

The expected output of this one looks like this:

[image]

The expected behavior is that tmux will support 256 color but not truecolor, and that your terminal will support both. If this is true, and your vim colorscheme still looks bad, it is very likely that you are using a truecolor colorscheme and tmux cannot support that. You can either switch to a 256 color version or just be sad about it. Sorry for the lack of good news.

Comment: Yes omg, you're right! Thank you. I decided to change the color scheme and airline theme to 256 colors, and now vim looks beautiful on tmux! I did not know that tmux was picky about its colors, thanks for the answer!